# IOS smallSocket and python

Tags: python, ios, sockets

I'm working on an IOS app.
I'm starting with a python server on mac that should connect to an iphone and print data sent from iphone.
the connection seems to be established but python print infinite " b " " as data... I don't know why.

the strange thing is that it happens also with cocoaAsynchronousSocket

this is the server

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import socket
import sys

addr = sys.argv[1]
port = 4444

if not addr :
    print ("No host address specified, plese specify an address", files=sys.stderr)

sock = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print ("connecting...")
try:
    sock.connect ((addr, port))
except socket.error: 
    print ("unable to connect to", addr)
    sys.exit(0)
print ("Connected to", addr)
while 1:
    data = sock.recv(0)
    data2 = sock.recv(1)
  #  if not data: break
    print (data)        
    print (data2)
```

and this is some code that i use to create the connection

```
- (IBAction)openPressed:(id)sender {


    socket = [Socket socket];
    [socket listenOnPort:4444]; 
    [socket acceptConnection];
    [socket writeString:@"connection accepted"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did u add this line:

> data = sock.recv(0)

Besides that, your sever, while client might be a better name, seems good.

If it doesn't print what you expect, I suggest that you use some sniffer tools, like [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), to check what it really receives.